# On The Topic of Zero

Tags: elementary-number-theory

One of the first things we learn in mathematics, is that division by zero is **indeterminate**/**undefined**  $(0)$

The set $\Bbb R$ of real numbers is closed under $+$, $-$, and $*$ but not under $/$ because of division by zero.

I kind of want to challenge that.

$\forall a, b, c \in \Bbb R$

$a \over b$ $= c$ $\iff$ $a \over c$ $= b$ $(1)$

$\forall a, x \in \Bbb R$

$a \over x$ $\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ $(2.1)$

$\forall a, x \in \Bbb R$

$a \over x$ $\to \infty$ as $x \to 0$   $(2.2)$

Taking the limit of $(2.1)$ and $(2.2)$ we get:

$\lim_{x \to 0}$ $a\over x$ = $\infty$  $(3.1)$

$\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $a\over x$ = $0$  $(3.2)$

In $(3.1)$ and $(3.2)$ above, supposing $a$ was $1$.

If we consider $0$ and $\infty$ multiplicative inverses, then $a \over 0$ can be written as $a({1}\over{0})$ and vice versa.

$\forall a, b, c \in \Bbb R$

$a^b = c$ $\implies c^{1\over b} = a$  $(4.1)$

Also it is an indentity that $\forall a \in \Bbb R$ $a^0 = 1$   $(5)$

$\forall a \in \Bbb R$

$a^x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ except when $x$ is in the form $p\over q$ and $q \mod 2 = 0$

$lim_{x \to 0} a^x = 1$

This proves $(5)$

From $(4.1)$

$a^0 = 1 \implies 1^{1\over 0} = a$  $(4.2)$

From $(4.2)$ we get

$1^\infty = a$  $(4.3)$

$(4.3) \implies a^{1\over\infty} = 1$ $(4.4)$

$lim_{x\to\infty} a^{1/x} = 1$ $(4.5)$
Except when $a$ is negative and $x$ is an even number.

$(4.5)$ proves $(4.4)$ which in turn proves $(4.3)$ which should prove $0$ and $\infty$ are multiplicative inverses.

Now $\infty$ is not defined so $(0)$ still holds.

My argument is that the inverse element for $0$ under $\cdot$ is $\infty$ which while undefined is still $\in \Bbb R$ Thus $\Bbb R$ is a commutative group under $\cdot$

Well, I just noticed that there are instances where it will be useful for me to consider $0$ and $\infty$ as multiplicative inverses.

Umm discuss?

Comment: You cannot say that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{a}{x}=\infty$. You can approach zero using negative numbers or positive numbers (or both alternatingly). Anyway, the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{a}{x}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, what about this: $3\cdot 0=0=4\cdot 0$. Multiplying by $\infty$ which you say is the inverse of $0$, we get that $3=4$.

Comment: You are not the first to try this and you won't be the last. But show yourself that the only ring in which the zero element is invertible is the zero ring.

Comment: I've just noticed scenarios in which treating $0$ and $\infty$ as multiplicative inverses would be very useful. I was trying to present an argument to **permit** such manipulation for such purposes.

Comment: @Mathematician 42, your first comment makes no sense to me. Please explain. $\frac{a}{x} \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$. So why I can't I take $\infty$ as the limit?

Comment: From the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)$$$$"If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)"$$$$

Comment: @TobiAlafin Because the right-sided limit is $\infty$ and the left-sided limit is $-\infty$. Saying $\frac{a}{x} \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ is plain wrong.

Comment: Indeed, what Stefan said.

Comment: Is there a way this can be placed in the chat then?

Comment: @Stefan, can I replace this with $+/-$ $\infty$ then?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to chat about this. I told you that it is impossible in my third comment and told you what to show in order to see this. Either you show this yourself or you look this up. Ignoring those options only shows that there is no discussion possible.

Comment: And no, you cannot replace it with $\pm \infty$. I told you that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{a}{x}$ does not exist. You can show this from the definition of a limit of a function.

Comment: This website is NOT for discussions. It is for asking answerable questions. Do you have a question, Tobi? I don't see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted we have $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x = \infty$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^-} 1/x = -\infty$. So defining $1/0 := \infty$ (in whatever sense) is a terrible idea, because it is no more canonical then $1/0 = -\infty$. Adding a new element $\pm \infty$ doesn't help: Is $\pm \infty > 0$ or $\pm \infty <0$?

Having $\infty$ as a "number" already creates a massive problem. What is $\infty - \infty$?. Well it should be $0$, right? But $(-\infty + \infty) + \infty = 0 +\infty = \infty$, while $-\infty + ( \infty + \infty) = -\infty + \infty = 0$. That's terrible, to put it mildly.

*Take the following with a grain of salt (!). It has its place in mathematics, but it comes with a trade off.*

The only reasonable thing we can do to keep most of what we know and love, including the ordering, is throwing subtraction away (that's the trade off) and only looking at the "numbers" from $0$ to $\infty$. Now we can certainly put $1/0 := \infty$ without worrying to much. But does this mean $0\cdot \infty = 1$?. No, because $0 = 2\cdot 0$ hence we would have $1 = 2$ by multiplying with $\infty$. The same goes for the other positive reals. It comes down to $0\cdot \infty \in \{0, \infty\}$. We should choose $0\cdot \infty = 0$ because now $a\cdot 0 = 0$ is true for *all* $a\in [0\,..\infty]$, which is way nicer then having to worry about different cases ("is $a = \infty$ or not?")

This is precisely what one does during the development of the Lebesgue integral in measure theory and it has been shown to be useful in this context.

However I need to stress again, that this construction comes with a trade off: We are losing subtraction! Therefore this is a hindrance for everday-mathematics.

Comment: I know there was no clear question formulated by the OP, but maybe this "answer" is satisfying enough to clarify the main issues.